# Is there a metals corrosion open dataset?

Tags: climate, technology

I am looking for a dataset to contain environment-metal details such as: humidity, temperature, chemistry, stress, erosion.

Is there a metals corrosion open dataset, or one from which you could get such data?

Answer (score 3):

For generic corrosive properties, this is a typical question for a scientific and engineering reference book, like the CRC Handbook (check your local library)

[image]

But for specific materials, these will come from the manufacturers. Try searching "corrosion tables" with some other keywords, until you find the one that works. Here are some examples:

https://www.materials.sandvik/en/materials-center/corrosion-tables/

https://www.materials.sandvik/en/materials-center/corrosion-tables/acetic-acid/

http://steelfinder.outokumpu.com/corrosion/ --> search "acetic acid"

[image]